# Metropolis is not working

Tags: beamer, patching, beamer-metropolis

I tried to use the `metropolis` beamer theme, but I got the following error

```
! Package beamerfontthememetropolis Error: Patching section title failed.
See the beamerfontthememetropolis package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... \patchcmd
```

Comment: That was an error that occurred with a versions of `beamer` and `metropolis` (see https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/247), if you update both it should work.

Answer (score 5):

> see https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/247 for details

This behaviour is due to a bug in `metropolis` which is fixed
in the `version 1.2` release. Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.