# How to compile .ins to .sty

Tags: beamer, miktex, patching, beamer-metropolis

Is there any way I can add `metropolis` package into MikTeX? I got this error:

```
! Package beamerfontthememetropolis Error: Patching section title failed.
See the beamerfontthememetropolis package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... \patchcmd
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The [CTAN Catalogue entry for `beamertheme-metropolis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis) documents, that the theme is part of the MiKTeX package `beamertheme-metropolis`. You can install it using the MiKTeX package manager. But I think, your problem is not missing the package. Maybe you are using a to old version of either the package or `beamer`. Run the MiKTeX update manager to make an update.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of your question [Metropolis is not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364530/35864) from not more than two hours ago. You even got a useful comment there. So if you have any further questions, comment on your old question before you open a new one with the same content just minutes later.